# Calculating the log(10) of a field in ArcMap using the field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser, log

I am trying to take the logarithmic function of a field in ArcMap 10.2 using the field calculator in my attribute table. I can't seem to find any equation that does this and the Help document did not have any formula for this.

I am self-taught ArcMap and still learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the field calculator, set your parser to python.

Then you can use the [`math.log10`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.log10) function.

Here, I'm updating a field called Log10Num with the log10 of a field called Number.

[image]